# Downloading Source Code from Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to download app from the google app engine using the following command:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <application-id> -V <application-version> <output-dir>
```

follow this link

http://code.google.com/intl/th-TH/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Source_Code

i got error.

```
Host: appengine.google.com
Fetching file list...
Error 403: --- begin server output ---
The download_app command is prohibited for this application.
--- end server output ---
```

How i fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Application downloading can be disabled for an application from the App Engine dashboard. Once it's been disabled, the application's code can never be downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Only the owner of an application can download it.  Do you own it?  If so, make sure you log in with the account that created the application.  Otherwise you won't be able to download the source.

From the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Source_Code):

> Only the developer who uploaded the code can download it. If anyone
>   other than that developer attempts to
>   download the app, they'll see an error
>   message like the following:
>
> ```
> Fetching file list...
> Email: user@example.com
> Password for user@example.com:
> Error 403: --- begin server output ---
> You do not have permission to download this app version.
> --- end server output ---
> ```